# iPhone MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am making an application and have made and uibarbuttonbuttonitem called send, when user click on that send button an email should send to the person which have been selected in mfmailcomposeviewcontroller without opening ui for that controller, I have made all the changes in mfmailcomposeviewcontroller and set the subject, receipents and all the other thing, however when I clicked on send button on uibarbutton mail didn't send through.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the key on your keyboard that says "Caps Lock" on it and press it.  There, now isn't that better?
2. If the `MFMailComposeViewController` UI is never shown to the user, then how can there be a "person who has been selected in the `MFMailComposeViewController`"?  If you want to subvert the standard e-mail composing UI then you need to provide your own UI that does it.  If you want to use the `MFMailComposeViewController` to send your e-mail, then you should use its built-in UI for composing the message.
3. If you're sure #2 is not an issue, then check your `UIBarButtonItem` configuration.  If you created it using the graphical interface-builder then verify that you have an appropriate IBAction assigned to the button, and that your IBAction implementation is being called as you expect.  Or if you are creating it programmatically then verify that you are setting the `target` and `action` options correctly.